# Visual Studio 2015 warns System.Runtime not found (but VS2013 is fine)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, I open a project that was created with Visual Studio 2013. Rebuild this project and see the following warning:

```
The referenced component 'System.Runtime' could not be found.
```

Looking at the References item in Solution Explorer, click System.Runtime, the Property window shows empty as below:

[image]

In Visual Studio 2013, it shows:

[image]

And this DLL does exist in the foler:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades

So Visual Studio 2013 didn't whow warnings when I build the project, but Visual Studio 2015 does.

Is this a bug or I miss something in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: A project that targets .NET 4.5 should never have a dependency on System.Runtime.  It is a "shim" assembly that is used in WinRT projects only.  Something unspeakable happened with this project before, probably a bad nuget package.  Delete the reference, see what hits the fan.

Comment: It is a project targeting 4.5. I deleted that reference and it compiles OK both with VS2013 and VS2015. Now with your explanation, I feel more safe to delete the reference and push to Git repo. Thank you Hans!

Comment: @HansPassant what would you suggest to do when we need it? (Toast notifications)

Comment: @HansPassant I also have this issue (alongside two other missing system assemblies). I can find no documentation to support your comment. Can you point to a resource that explains/confirms this?

Comment: As long as nobody wants to document what exactly hits the fan then there's not a wholeheckofalot of pointing going on.  Sigh.

Comment: @HansPassant Still you should make your comment the answer. I'd accept it. #WorkedForMe

Answer (score 1):

Include `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` instead of `System.Runtime`. It worked for me.