# Can't add reference to System.IO, System.Runtime and System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with Visual Studio Community 2015 on a Visual Basic application targeting `.NET 4.5`. I didn't write the application so I added all the missing dependencies using `NuGet` but there are 3 dependencies I can't add no matter what I try. This is one of the many errors I get when building the project:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.

This are the dependencies:

- System.IO
- System.Runtime
- System.Threading.Tasks

I tried installing them with `NuGet` but I get this error for example when trying to install `System.IO` that also installs `System.Runtime` and `System.Threading.Tasks`:

> Could not install package 'System.Runtime 4.0.20'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I also tried to add them manually adding the `.dll` that in my case are in:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.IO.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll`

But doesn't work neither. I also tried removing `System.Runtime` as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607272/visual-studio-2015-warns-system-runtime-not-found-but-vs2013-is-fine#comment51166781_31607272) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30270034/1335209%20%22%22), both without any success.

This is an image of my `References`:

[image]

Comment: System.Runtime 4.0.20 requires NET4.6. I think it's a problem with the NuGet Package as reported here https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1243

Comment: Did anyone figure out a fix for this?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Me too face this problem. I have resolved this issue by

1. Removing the bin & obj folder
   You can use below command to clear your projects bin & obj folders.
   Open your commend prompt, Go to your project's root director then run below commends

   ```
   FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%G

   FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S obj') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%G
   ```
2. Delete the temp files in my machine

To avoid this problem in future, maintain separate folder (DependentAssembly) to store those assemblies. When nuget restore the packages, it will update a new package dll. So, there might be chance to get build error, due to made some changes existing methods in new assemblies.
[image]